# SQL search query in relations tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, pdo

I am trying to make an sql search query to return only ORDERS that match my search keyword. The issue is that i also need to search in every comments body for each order and if a result is found in that comment the order for that comment should be selected.  The tables looks like this in a simplified way:

```
ORDERS:

ID = 95
title = first order


COMMENT RELATIONS:
id = 1241
comment_id = 500
target_id = 95
type = order

COMMENTS: 
id = 500
body = this is the first comment
```

So if i searched for "first comment" the order with id 95 should be selected.

My current attempt seems to select more then order but also their comments and relations? This is how my current attempt looks like.

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM orders as o
LEFT JOIN comment_relations as cr ON o.id = target_id
LEFT JOIN comments as c ON cr.comment_id = c.id
WHERE o.id LIKE :keyword OR o.title LIKE :keyword OR c.body LIKE :keyword';
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which database you are using but in most databases you can use the table alias follow by * for selecting only one table.

```
'SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM orders as o
LEFT OUTER JOIN comment_relations as cr ON o.id = target_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments as c ON cr.comment_id = c.id
WHERE o.id LIKE :keyword OR o.title LIKE :keyword OR c.body LIKE :keyword';
```

Comment: thanks this gets me closer. The problem i noticed now is that i ONLY get comments inside my result now. If i search for an orders id i get its comments back. What i need is to get the order connected to that comment back.

Comment: @JarJarJosh I am not sure if I understood the question but In the select we are selecting o.* which means it only shows you the order fields. 
you can can change the query to :
'SELECT DISTINCT o.id, c.body ...' to select the order id and its comment

Comment: Sorry i had forgot to add o.* to the select. That helped a lot with what im trying to accomplish. Now the other issue as you see i am trying to find the correct orders by searching in the orders id and orders title and comments body. When im searching for a order without any comments and im only searching by ID it doesn't return any orders?

Comment: @JarJarJosh You need outer join for that. Changed the answer to use outer join

Answer (score 0):

As per your concept i create 3 demo tables in phpmyadmin which description is here.

1.orders have columns (id,title).

2.comment_relations have columns (id,comment_id,target_id,type).

3.comments have columns (id,body).

This is SQL Query for fetch records from order by match keyword from comments table.

```
select DISTINCT o.* from orders o LEFT JOIN comment_relations cr ON o.id=cr.target_id LEFT JOIN comments c ON c.id=cr.comment_id where body LIKE '%keyword%'
```

On applying this query by replace your keyword at place of keyword you get this result.

[image: Result page]

Here i match keyword "first comment"